# JSON.stringify in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

How do I get reference of the `<div>` `id` and title from a external JS by using the code below:

```js
function recordedEvent() {    
    var v_Id = $(this).attr('Id');
    var v_Title = $(this).attr('Title');
    var o = { Title : v_Title, ObjectId : v_Id };
    alert(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

The function is called in the HTML with a `onclick` called `box1()`.

Code in `CplTemplateSetup.js` is where I want to run the function from into the HTML:

```
content_left_30_four_click_images_right_70_head_content_template.html
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**P.S.**: [JSON data (*zip archive*)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4swbqb0rw6o0cps/AAAJppbNFwC0dI5Dt0xw7a7Pa?dl=0)

Comment: "run a JSON in a function in that js" What do you mean by "run a JSON"? JSON is just data.

Comment: I would like to run those 4 lines of code in the js and link it up to the click with a function from the js. So that if i ever need to change it, i only need to do it in the js and not in every html template

Comment: JSON is a data serialization format; it doesn't "run".

Comment: In that case, I believe you already have your answer. Put that code into a separate JS file and load it anywhere you're using your templates.

Comment: Its doesn't work, it won't come back with the id and title of the element clicked, thats the issue that i am having

Comment: You didn't specify that. Is this code running after your `.box` elements are loaded? Consider wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Its wrapped in this in the html and works but not in the external js, just tried that and can't get the alert

Comment: It's impossible to say anymore without seeing the generated HTML.

Comment: its not online at the moment and new to this so not sure how to send it over

Comment: Make sure you load jQuery **before** you load the external JS.

Comment: When you run the external JS, are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: No the alert there are no errors, just the alert comes back blank

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4swbqb0rw6o0cps/AAAJppbNFwC0dI5Dt0xw7a7Pa?dl=0

Comment: Surprised this works ... shouldn't `Id` be `id` and `Title` be `title` - i.e. these attributes are lower case in DOM elements (regardless of how they are written in the HTML) - or does jquery "help" novices by internally changing the supplied attribute to lower case? ... rather than `var v_Id = $(this).attr('id');` etc, I'd be using `var v_Id = this.id;` etc

Comment: It works fine in the html doc and pulls in the id and title with it being capitals. It just won't get them in the external js

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and see that jQuery does indeed "help" in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the most obvious problem is that you don't have a closing parenthesis after your callback.. otherwise the code looks good

---

### Edit

```
window.lastClickedBoxData = {}; // just reassign that within your function
```

or

```
window.runThisWhenClicked = function () {
    var v_Id = $(this).attr('Id');
    var v_Title = $(this).attr('Title');
    var o = { Title : v_Title, ObjectId : v_Id };
};
```

then just

```
$(".box").click(window.runThisWhenClicked);
```

Comment: Which bit is that on then? Been looking at the code for too long probably just missed it

Comment: At the very end, you have `.click(function () { ... };` instead of `... });`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out. The thing I am trying to do is get the code into the external js. The code runs because the alert plays but I can't seem to get reference to the div Id in the external js

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem that you're facing would be apparent to anyone who doesn't view your code.

You defined a function within a script tag, in the html, and called that function in the `onclick` attribute of the box being clicked on. To that function, `this` refers to the box that was clicked on. From there, you call a function within an external js document. In that function, `this` refers to the window object. In other words, for the code that you posted, `$(this)` is a jquery instance of the window object which doesn't have the attributes that you're looking for, such as `id` and `title`, so they're blank.

To see what I'm talking about open the console and add the following line of code to each of your functions:

```
console.log(this);
```

If you're having trouble doing that, the following code should work as well, but it's not as good for debugging:

```
alert(this);
```

You need all of your code to be in the html script tag or in the external document. Also, you shouldn't define the function to be called during a click event using `onclick` within the html. It's better to do it using javascript or jquery so that your javascript is completely separate from your html.

**EDIT**: You shouldn't update your question with an answer. You should edit the original question with this information so that anyone having a similar problem can find the solution. I'd have commented on the answer directly, but I don't have the reputation to do this.